flutter redirect to login page if refresh Token is expired, but application theme is not being applied
I'm building a flutter application that uses tokens for users authentication , what i want is that when the refresh token is expired i want to redirect the user to the login page , my application uses MVVM as structural pattern , including http interceptor using dio package , what I've done is that I've implemented a RefreshTokenViewModel and injecting it inside the dio interceptor , and by using the jwt_decoder package I'm checking before sending the request if the access token is expired or not , if it is expired , I'm sending the refreshToken request to get new accesstoken and a new refreshToken.
so what I've tried is that i made the main widget (root widget of the application) listen to refreshTokenViewModel state and get notified by using Consumer (redirect to login page if refreshToken request failed or proceed the request)
but my problem is that when the login page is being displayed (after redirecting)  it does not include any of the application theme so the predefined theme is not included at all , 
i think the problem is that the main widget is not implemented in the correct way
i will include some code snippets as well to be reviewed and also if there is another proper way to achieve this behavior
interceptor logic :
///onRequest method
 String? token = await SharedPreferenceManager.getAccessToken();
    if (token != null && token.isNotEmpty) {
      bool isTokenExpired = JwtDecoder.isExpired(token);
      if (isTokenExpired) {
        token = await refreshTokenViewModel.refreshToken();
      }
      options.headers.addAll({'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'});
    }
    return handler.next(options);

refreshTokenViewModel :
  Future<void> refreshToken() async {
    var response = await refreshTokenRepository.refreshToken();
    if (response is Failure) {
      setFailure(Error(response.errorMessage));
    } else {
      setSuccess();
    }
  }

main.dart :
// This widget is the root of your application.
class _MyAppState extends ConsumerState<MyApp> {

...//

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(builder: (context, ref, child) {
      ref.watch(themeRProvider);
      ref.watch(refreshTokenViewModelProvider);

      isRefreshTokenInAppFailure = refreshTokenViewModel.refreshTokenState ==
          RefreshTokenState.failure;

      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        if (isRefreshTokenInAppFailure) {
          NavigatorUtils.pushReplacement(context, LoginPage()); ///when pushing the login page it is not taking the theme of the app maybe because the material app is being returned after
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Your Session expired'),
              content: Text('You need to login again....'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: const Text('OK'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      });

      return MaterialApp(
        themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode == ThemeModeOption.light
            ? ThemeMode.light
            : themeProvider.themeMode == ThemeModeOption.dark
            ? ThemeMode.dark
            : ThemeMode.system,
        theme: lightTheme,
        darkTheme: darkTheme,
        home: SplashPage(),
      );
    });
  }



